# ! Missing } inserted. all the time!

Tags: amsmath

```
\begin{multline}
(3 + 2\omega )\left( \frac{{B\prime (r)}}{{2A(r)B(r)}}\varphi \prime  + \frac{1}{{A(r)}}\varphi \prime \prime  - \frac{{A\prime (r)}}{{2{A^2}(r)}}\varphi \prime  + \frac{2}{{rA(r)}}\varphi \prime  \right) \\
+ \frac{{16\pi G\lambda }}{{{\varphi ^2}}}\left[ { - \frac{{19\varphi {\prime ^2}\varphi \prime \prime }}{{2{A^2}(r)\varphi }} + \frac{{19A\prime (r)\varphi {\prime ^3}}}{{4{A^3}(r)\varphi }} \\
+ \frac{{B{\prime ^2}(r)}}{{4{A^2}(r){B^2}(r)}}\varphi {\prime ^2} - \frac{{5A{\prime ^2}(r)}}{{4{A^4}(r)}}\varphi {\prime ^2} - \frac{2}{{{r^2}{A^2}(r)}}\varphi {\prime ^2}} \right]
\end{multline}
```

I've tried `split` and `align` and I get the same message!

```
! Missing } inserted!
```

Can't figure it out, hope that you can help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's a very common problem: you can't start `\left` in a row of the alignment and have the matching `\right` in another one.

Comment: Ty!! how do i put () or []?

Comment: `\left( .....    \right.` in one row and `\left.   ....\right)` on the other. Dot signals *consider this as the missing delimiter* to TeX

Comment: use manual scaling, i.e., `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg` instead of `\left...\right`

Comment: Or better still, just don't do it!  Re-format to avoid the problem.

Comment: @percusse, not at good idea in general if the enclosed material does not have the same size

Comment: Really? so its not \left(.....\right) +.... \left(.....\right)??

Comment: @daleif Also true but that can be ignored at this level.

Comment: percusse i tried your typing and get same problem :/

Comment: @percusse, other people will read these suggestions and use them on their problems, and the need to know that the `\left ..... \right.` ... `\left. ... \right` solution does not work in all cases. The manual scaling does.

Comment: @daleif I'm not saying it's right to use dot notation in all cases but I hope you would agree that this should be known too. There are many delimiter sizing questions on the site but not any on this detail. Besides they can also follow these comments too to get additional info.

Answer (score 3):

You have some abundance of braces which are not necessarily a problem but difficult to debug.

Also every line in the tabulated math is considered to be a valid entity on its own hence if you put an opening/closing delimiter TeX wants to find the matching pair. To signal that the missing pair is omitted on purpose you need to put `\left.` or `\right.` to do so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
(3 + 2\omega )\left(
    \frac{B\prime (r)}{2A(r)B(r)}\varphi\prime + \frac{1}{A(r)}\varphi\prime \prime  - \frac{A\prime (r)}{2{A^2}(r)}\varphi\prime + \frac{2}{rA(r)}\varphi\prime
\right) \\
+ \frac{16\pi G\lambda}{\varphi ^2}\left[
    - \frac{{19\varphi {\prime ^2}\varphi \prime \prime }}{{2{A^2}(r)\varphi }} + \frac{19A\prime(r)\varphi\prime ^3}{4{A^3}(r)\varphi } 
\right.\\
\left. 
    + \frac{B{\prime ^2}(r)}{4{A^2}(r){B^2}(r)}\varphi\prime^2 - \frac{{5A{\prime ^2}(r)}}{{4{A^4}(r)}}\varphi {\prime ^2} - \frac{2}{{{r^2}{A^2}(r)}}\varphi {\prime ^2}
\right] 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as commented this will be ugly if the size of the terms differ on different rows as the sizes won't matter. I would strongly suggest shuffling your terms and make it more readable.

Comment: Don't use `\varphi\prime` etc. This gives ugly resul. Use `\vaphi'`.

Comment: its not just these terms... its 2 pages. It would be hard to find a nice way to shuffle them. If i use split wont it be prettier?

Comment: yeah i know it, i will fix it wipet

Comment: @John Then separate the terms and work them term-by-term. If it's two pages long nobody, and I'm pretty sure about it, will read it. So it's gonna be a wasted work. It cannot be the only way.

Comment: @percusse ty a lot for your help mate!! Ok i will try to fix it! Ty again!!

Comment: @John My pleasure

Comment: not only is every *line* a unit, but (in the case of `align` and friends), every segment delimited by `&` is a unit when it comes to matching delimiters.  *much* better to take the `\big...` route.

Comment: @barbara I know what you are addressing but I'm not so sure about that. Guessing the size is as difficult as forgetting delimiters.

Comment: @percusse -- yes, getting the size right is a pain.  one can always use `\left. ... \right\}` (or whatever) for a first cut, then replace the "live" delimiters by an appropriate `\big...` form.  (it helps to have a crib sheet showing the sizes, in typical uses, for handy reference.)